# AutoCompleteExtender showing all 500 options every time

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocompleteextender

I have a textbox with AutoCompleteExtender, instead of using a webservice I just have a method in code behind that pulls a list of string names from an xml.  Now every time you start in the text box , the AutoCompleteExtender shows up with all 500 names in it.  There is no order either ( ex. if I type "Riha" to start typing "Rihana" you'd think only strings that start with "Riha" would show up, but all 500 show up, not even in any order.  I tried setting CompletionSetCount="5" , but no luck.  Is there an easy fix to this?

This Part of the Code I believe is functioning properly...

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
{
    XmlDocument xmlArtist = new XmlDocument();        
    xmlArtist.Load(string.Format(" http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists&api_key={0}&limit=500",  key));
    List<string> topartists = new List<string>();
             foreach (XmlNode node in xmlArtist.SelectNodes("lfm/artists/artist"))
             {                     
                 topartists.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText.ToString());
             }
             return topartists;            
}
```

Here is .aspx code

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnterBand" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Width="400px"  >     </asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtEnterBand_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEnterBand" ServiceMethod="GetNames" UseContextKey="true" ServicePath="" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="5"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: Why not limit what gets returned in your code behind? instead of foreach, do a for (i = 0; i<5; i++) ? or some such?

Comment: Btw, CompletionSetCount is passed to your web service, it doesn't limit anything on it's own

Comment: I thought that the AutoCompleteExtender automatically compared whats in the text box to the list , I thought there was just a property that I was missing.   Do I have to pass whats in the textbox and compare it to all 500 names manually each time?

Comment: It makes calls continuous calls to your webservice with more and more values, something like prefix = "mysea", then prefix = "mysear", prefix = "mysearc" etc etc. So you should be comparing and limiting in your method

Comment: Ok, that's easy I guess, I just thought it compared on it's own - Also 1 more thing , how can I store the List topartists in memory somewhere so it doesn't have to request it every time.  it won't let me access Session State from that GetNames method. Any suggestions on how to store that List temporarly?

Comment: I think you can access an application variable from your static methods

Comment: I cannot access variables from static methods

Answer (score 2):

```
GetNames(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
   return topartists.Take(count).ToList();
}
```

In Source page:

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
UseContextKey="True"  TargetControlID="txtAuto" ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" 
MinimumPrefixLength="2" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" 
CompletionSetCount="10" FirstRowSelected="false" 
OnClientItemSelected="ClientItemSelected">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Add this property`UseContextKey="True"` in the `<asp:AutoCompleteExtender>` tag.